# ReactJs: Passing url param to outside functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, react-redux

I'm working on an Isomorphic react application using redux. I'm having issues passing a url parameter into a function that dispatches a redux action.

```
class SingleMovie extends Component { 
    componentDidMount(){
        console.log(this.props.match.params.id); // i can access the id here
    } 
     ..... 
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {movie:state.movie};
}


function loadData(store, id){  //<--how do i get the id parameter 
    return store.dispatch(fetchMovie(id)); //<--so i can pass it here 
}

export default {
loadData,
component: connect(mapStateToProps,{fetchMovie})(SingleMovie)
};
```

What i tried:

(1) Declare a constant outside the React component

```
let id = "";

class SingleMovie extends Component { 
...
```

(2) Try to assign the global variable with the id

```
componentDidMount(){
    id= this.props.match.params.id;
}
```

**The id always ends up being undefined.**

Answer (score 0):

First save the id params to the state, and then use **setState's callback** function to dispatch the **fetchMovie** action.

```
class SingleMovie extends Component { 
  constructor(){
    this.state = {
      id: ""
    }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    //console.log(this.props.match.params.id);
    this.getMovieId(this.props.match.params.id);
  }
  getMovieId = (movieId) => {
    this.setState({
      id: movieId
    }, () => {
      this.loadData();
    })
  }
  loadData = (store) => {
    store.dispatch(fetchMovie(this.state.id));
  }
  render(){
    return(
      ...
    )
  }
```

Comment: thanks, but now i get a  error saying: ReferenceError: store is not defined. how do i get the store accessible to the callback.

Comment: do you mean store.dispatch(getMovieId(this.state.id)); or store.dispatch(fetchMovie(this.state.id));..I get a new error saying TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined

Comment: fetchMovie is what I said.